# refresh content table in html by an onChange of a dropdown menu.

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, onchange

I'm working on a project where I have to refresh a table. The refreshing of the table is done by choosing a year in a drop down menu. So somebody chooses a year (in this case 2012, 2013 or 2014) and then the table under the dropdown menu will change it contents according to the value of the dropdown menu. For example:

`<p>which year you were born? <select name="select" onChange="?">`

`<option value="1">2012</option>`

`<option value="2">2013</option>`

`<option value="3" selected="selected">2014</option>`

The contents of the tables are all different files. For example for 2012 there is a file  which is already prepared for the webpage for only 2012, etc.

So it should do the following.
1. A year is chosen
2. Find specific file that belongs to year.
3. Copy content of that file into the source of the html
4. refresh the page so the new table is shown

I'm so new to this subject that I have absolutely no clue where to start.

Thank you!

Regards,
Sjaak.

Comment: were you able to solve the isse with the answer provided?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

add id to your select element

```
<p>which year you were born? 
<select id="select-id" name="select">
<option value="1">2012</option> 
<option value="2">2013</option> 
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>adress</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id='sample'></tbody>
</table>
```

**JS/Jquery**

On assumption that your files are html/php files already created with the required data
Attach event to your select onchange,

On change you can fire ajax call so that there is no need to refresh the page, the load will load the content inside the selector provided so in your case I have given `sample` id to your tbody. In load you can full path or relative path

```
$('#select-id').on('change', function () {
   var val = $(this).text(); // gives you 2012, 2013, 2014
   $('#sample').load('yourdomain.com' + val + '.html', function () {
    alert('content was loaded'); // call back after content is loaded
   });
});
```

[Jquery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/u8cXA/)**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have something. I made a table wit

Comment: @sjaakvanboer I didnt get your comment. Can you please explain in detail

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still have something. 

What it should do is something like this:
`<p>which year you were born?` 
`<select id="select-id" name="select" onChange="?">`
`<option value="1">2012</option>`
`<option value="2">2013</option>`

`<table>`
`<thead>`
 `<tr>`
  `<th>name</th>`
  `<th>adress</th>`
 `<tr>`
</thead>`
`<tbody>`
HERE SHOULD BE CONTENT OF THE OTHER HTML PAGE, WHICH ONLY CONSISTS OF THE BODY FILE
`</tbody>`
`</table>`

Comment: Raunak, thank you for your demo. It was really useful and I try to follow it a little. I copied your code in the demo and added my changes. I try to make it work, but if I start my website it is not working. I will post my code in a few minutes in the next comment. Could you have a look at it?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$('#select-id').on('change', function () {
alert($(this).val());
$('#sample').load('C:\Desktop\body_' + var + '.html' , function () {
alert('content was loaded'); // call back after content is loaded
});
});
}); 
</script>
<p>Select year:<select id="select-id" name="select">
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>adress</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody id='sample'></tbody>
</table>`

Comment: Replace var in  "var + '.html'" to $(this).val(), everything else seems fine